# Using Python's Tkinter, how do I save data to use only on that application?

Tags: database, python-3.x, button, tkinter, save

I'm just trying to make an application where I can create characters and save them into the application only. I'm not sure how to save it without doing it onto the computer itself. It'll have two options on the main screen, one to be to create and the other to view profiles. I don't know how to connect the them. I'll put the code up, but it's only a small piece of it to save space.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

class Application(Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    self.minsize(width=1300, height=750)
    self.maxsize(width=1300, height=750)

    container = Frame(self)
    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    #there will be another page for profiles
    self.frames={}
    for F in (Startpage, Createpage):
        page_name = F.__name__
        frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames[page_name] = frame

        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

    self.show_frame("Startpage")

def show_frame(self, page_name):
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.tkraise()


class Startpage(Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    self.configure(bg='white')

    headLabel = Label(self, text="Character Profiles", font=("Times New Roman", 36), bg='white', height=2)
    headLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=25, sticky='n')

    createButton = Button(self, text="Create", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg="black", fg="white", width=30, height=2,
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Createpage"))
    createButton.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=30, pady=2, sticky="sw")

    profilesButton = Button(self, text="Profiles", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg="black", fg="white", width=30, height=2)
    profilesButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=2, sticky="se")

    spacer1 = Label(self, bg='white', width=33)
    spacer1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=20)

class Createpage(Frame):
 def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    self.configure(bg='white')

    backButton = Button(self, text="back", font=("Times New Roman", 20), bg='black', fg='white',
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Startpage"))
    backButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

    headLabel = Label(self, text="Create a New Character", font=("Times New Roman", 24), bg='white')
    headLabel.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=10, pady=2)

    img = PhotoImage(file="rsz_profilepic.png")

    picLabel = Label(self, image=img, borderwidth=0)
    picLabel.image = img
    picLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2, columnspan=4)


    fullnameLabel = Label(self, bg="white", text="Full Name: ", font=("Times New Roman", 16))
    fullnameLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=2, sticky="E")
    #this would be the file name
    fullnameEntry = Entry(self, font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg="#EEEEEE")
    fullnameEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=0, pady=2, sticky="w")

    nicknameLabel = Label(self, font=("Times New Roman", 16), text="Alias: ", bg="white")
    nicknameLabel.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)

    aliasEntry = Entry(self, font=("Times New Roman", 16), bg="#EEEEEE")
    aliasEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, sticky="W")

    sexLabel = Label(self, text="Sex: ", bg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 16))
    sexLabel.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)

    v = IntVar()
    male = Radiobutton(self, text="Male", bg="white", variable=v, value=1)
    female = Radiobutton(self, text="Female", bg="white", variable=v, value=2)
    other = Radiobutton(self, text="Other", bg="white", variable=v, value=3)
    male.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="w")
    female.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky="w")
    other.grid(row=4, column=3, sticky="w")

    ageLabel = Label(self, text="Age: ", bg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 14))
    ageLabel.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)

    ageEntry = Entry(self, font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg="#EEEEEE")
    ageEntry.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=0, pady=2, sticky="w")

    statusLabel = Label(self, text="Status: ", bg="white", font=("Times New Roman", 14))
    statusLabel.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)

    s = IntVar()
    alive = Radiobutton(self, text="Alive", bg="white", variable=s, value=1)
    deceased = Radiobutton(self, text="Deseased", bg="white", variable=s, value=2)
    alive.grid(row=6, column=1, sticky="w")
    deceased.grid(row=6, column=2, sticky="w")

    bigassFrame = Frame(self, bg='white', width=1000, height=1000)
    bigassFrame.grid(row=1, column=4, rowspan=50, padx=10, pady=2)

    #there are more buttons below these two
    generalButton = Button(bigassFrame, text="General", font=("Times New Roman", 14), width=25, fg='white', bg='black')
    generalButton.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

    appearanceButton = Button(bigassFrame, text="Appearance", font=("Times New Roman", 14), width=25, fg='white', bg='black')
    appearanceButton.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=2)

    #here is where the information to be stored is
    genFrame = Frame(self, bg='white')
    genFrame.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=10, pady=2)

    nameLabel = Label(genFrame, text="Name: ", font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg='white')
    nameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)
    nameEntry = Entry(genFrame, font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg="#EEEEEE")
    nameEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=0, pady=2)

    namemeaningLabel = Label(genFrame, text="Name Meaning: ", font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg='white')
    namemeaningLabel.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)
    namemeaningEntry = Entry(genFrame, font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg="#EEEEEE")
    namemeaningEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=2)

    q1Label = Label(genFrame, text="Who named him/her?", font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg='white')
    q1Label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=0, pady=2)
    q1Entry = Entry(genFrame, font=("Times New Roman", 14), bg="#EEEEEE")
    q1Entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=0, pady=2)


    #this button will save a copy of the information to the profiles page
    saveButton = Button(self, text="Save", font=("Times New Roman", 14))
    saveButton.grid(row=0, column=7)


if __name__ == "__main__":
 app = Application()
 app.title("Character Profiles")
 app.geometry("1000x800+20+20")
 app.mainloop()
```

I've never posted a question on here before, so I'm not sure if I did it right.

Comment: In the future try to include less code. That is a lot to look through, particularly when it isn't all relevant to your question. I've seen much worse first questions.

Comment: Are you asking how to save data in python between closing and opening the application?

Comment: @jcolemang yeah. When you close it, the information will still be there when you open it back up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would recommend starting out with is to use text files. There is a tutorial for reading and writing text files [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python). The idea is to save all of your data in a known format which you will be able to read later. The most common way to do this is to let every entity (profile in your case) be a line in the file and each property of the entity be separated by a comma. I don't know exactly what kind of profiles you are storing, but here is a generic example:

To create a profile, add it to the end of your `profiles.txt` file

```
first_name = 'john'
last_name = 'doe'
favorite_language = 'python'
file = open('profiles.txt', 'a') # 'a' for append. Don't overwrite old content
file.write(first_name + ',' + last_name + ',' + favorite_language)
file.close()
```

Then, to read all of the profiles:

```
file = open('profiles.txt', 'r')
lines = file.read_lines()
for line in lines:
    info = line.split(',')
    first_name = info[0]
    last_name = info[1]
    fav_language = info[2]
    # do something with this info
file.close()
```

You could also store the profiles in objects, maybe something like this:

```
class Profile():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, fav_language):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.fav_language = fav_language

    def save(self):
        file = open('profiles.txt', 'a')
        file.write(first_name + ',' + last_name + ',' + favorite_language)
        file.close()
```

Of course, this method is **far** from perfect. For example, what happens if the user enters a comma in their name? Now `split` is either returning incorrect information or you're getting an error. If you want this to be really robust you have to do all sorts of string processing to make it at least difficult to break, or you could just not allow users to use commas in their names.

A final note, the way people generally solve the problem you're having in the "real world" is to use databases. If you're interested, look into something like MySQL, Postgresql, or MongoDB. They are far more complicated than writing text files but work much better. They are essentially separate programs on your computer dedicated to saving and retrieving data for you.